# troubleshoot - $ django-admin.py: command not found

Tags: python, django

```
leavemealone:~ test$ django-admin.py startproject mysite
-bash: django-admin.py: command not found
leavemealone:~ test$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py /usr/local/bin/django-admin.py
ln: /usr/local/bin/django-admin.py: File exists
leavemealone:~ test$ django-admin.py startproject.py
-bash: django-admin.py: command not found
leavemealone:~ test$
```

So, as a disclaimer, I might be an idiot.

I followed the install instructions on djangoproject.com, and followed their solution to the command not found error, yet it persists. I literally have no idea what to do at this point.

Comment: Is ''/usr/local/bin/'' on $PATH?

Comment: Care to search before posting - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%24+django-admin.py%3A+command+not+found Its a reference issue, are you using virtual env?

Comment: @xbello, I dont know. how would I check/ set it on $PATH?

Comment: @Mutant I know this is a common problem but I don't know what my particular problem is specifically so I wanted to talk with people and hopefully find someone to walk me through possible solutions one at a time and can understand what the next thing to check is. i downloaded virtual env, but again Im just getting started trying to do stuff like this and am completely ignorant as to how/where things should be to work properly. So I have virtual env but don't think I'm using it. i installed django with 'pip install django'

Comment: @user3150759 type ''echo $PATH''

Comment: @xbello leavemealone:    ~ test$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

Comment: @user3150759 Does the file "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py" exists? "dist-packages" is probably an Ubuntu path, and this system renames "django-admin.py" to "django-admin", so maybe you have to use "django-admin startproject mysite".

Comment: @xbello okay, so apparently that path WAS incorrect. I think I just copy/pasted that path from an answer to somebody else's problem. this is the correct path : "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py" but I'm still getting the same exact errors as before. when I re-did the "ln -s" command again with the new correct path, I just get "file exists" so I'm not sure if it is actually changing where it's trying to link the file from or not...

Comment: @user3150759 I would delete the link ''django-admin.py'' (it's probably a dead link) in /usr/local/bin, and create it again pointing the right command. I always work with <TAB> key (completion) to ensure the files are there.

Comment: @xbello thank you so much for your help, that solved that problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution in comments, also was here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/faq/troubleshooting/. Take care the files exists, the `$PATH` includes the path to `django-admin.py`, and the symlinks are correctly asigned

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to set the `$PATH`, then you can just use one long command in `Bash` to start a new project.  Like so:

```
python ~/path/to/django-admin.py startproject <project_name>
```

A common path might be:

```
python ~/documents/virtualenvs/pay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py startproject store
```